# I want to input to CSV with Python 3, but I'd like to do it from now on

Tags: python, csv

Premise / What you want to achieve
Obtain data such as stock code and stock name from the Web with Python 3
I'd like to output in CSV, but I'm having a problem because the arrangement is not ideal.

Problems / error messages that are occurring
At present, we have succeeded in arranging the stock code and stock name.
Next, I would like to output to CSV in the following arrangement.

Brand code 1, Brand name 1
Brand code 2, Brand name 2
Brand code 3, Brand name 3
...
...
...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

# Yahoo!finance

url = "https://info.finance.yahoo.co.jp/ranking/?kd=27&mk=1&tm=d&vl=a"
l = list()
t = list()
num = 1
while num <= 51:
 r = requests.get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
 codes = soup.select("#contents-body-bottom > div.rankdata > div.rankingTableWrapper > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(" + str(num) + ") > td:nth-child(1) > a")
 if len(codes) == 0:
  break
 num += 1
 for code in codes:
    l.append(code.text)


base_url = "https://kabutan.jp/stock/?code="
num = 0
for i in l:
 url = base_url + str(l[num])
 r = requests.get(url)
 soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
 titles = soup.select("#kobetsu_right > div.company_block > h3")

 num += 1
 for title in titles:
  t.append(title.text)

# csv

with open('data.csv', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writerow(l)
    writer.writerow(t)
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSV with one line using the `zip ()` function in the standard function and the `zip_longest ()` function in `itertoolsK`

```
for row in zip(l, t):
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice!
The output was as ideal.

I became more and more interested in Python because there were many useful functions I didn't know about.